# Finding of an equivalence class

Tags: group-theory, equivalence-relations

We define group A as such:
$A=\{n\epsilon\mathbb{N}:1\le n\le 90\}$

We define relation R on A as such:
$aRb\iff23|(a+22b)$
(where "$|$" represents divisibility)

What is the equivalence class $[22]_R$ equal to?

An explanation of how you found this would be very helpful as I have been unable to find an explanation for any similar problems.

Comment: Modulo or divisibility?

Comment: If $23|(a+22b)$ returns the remainder, what is the relation? You have to put a proposition $(aRb\iff \textrm{"Proposition"})$, not a number. Do you mean the remainder has to be $0$? (Which means that "|" represent divisibility)

Comment: I think you are correct, it is divisibility!

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* Note that $23 \mid (a+22b)$ iff $23 \mid (a-b)$ iff $a$ and $b$ leave the same remainder when divided by $23$.

If $a \in \mathbb N$ then $a= 23q+r$ with $0 \le r \le 22$. Then $[a]_R=[r]_R=\{ 23q+r : q \in \mathbb N \} = r +23  \mathbb N $.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure how to use this information.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I dont understand how I am to use this to make the group for $[22]_R$

Comment: could you clarify a little?

Answer (score 1):

$aRb\iff23|(a+22b)$

$22Rb\iff23|(22+22b)\iff23|(22(1+b))$

$22$ and $23$ are coprime, so $23$ must divide $1+b$, that is

$1+b=23m\iff b=23m-1=23m'+22$ for some $m,m'\in\mathbf{Z}$.

So $22Rb\iff b=23m+22$

And therefore $$[22]_R=\left\{c\in\mathbf{Z}\left|\right.\exists k\in\mathbf{Z}\, c=23k+22\right\}$$